Git tag in github workflow sometimes fails to resolve commit
I have a github workflow for the release process of an application. Part of this workflow is to set a tag on a commit and push that to the remote.
Sometimes the tag command fails with a message like fatal: Failed to resolve 'dae733fe' as a valid ref.
Most of the times it works though and I am stumped what the issue is. Also when running the same command locally it works. So the commit hash seems to be fine and not ambiguous.
The workflow itself is rather simple, it perfoms a checkout, then uses docker cli to build/tag/push images and then tags the commit from the image name with the release number.
Has anyone encountered this behavior or has an idea how I can gather additional information?
There are a lot of similar questions but those I found usually refer to HEAD or some other named reference or are in regard to unusual setups.
Update: Anonymized workflow file
name: Deploy Produktion

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      konsolidierung_tag:
        description: 'Konsolidierung Docker Tag (e.g. 1.5.1-20240617.141322-c9a31b61-KONSOLIDIERUNG)'
        type: string
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    name: Deploy Produktion
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, on-prem ]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Create PRODUKTION Docker Image Tag
        run: |
          PRODUKTION_TAG=$(echo "${{github.event.inputs.konsolidierung_tag}}" | sed 's/KONSOLIDIERUNG/PRODUKTION/I')
          echo "PRODUKTION_IMAGE=<docker-tag-prefix>:$PRODUKTION_TAG" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Create PRODUKTION Docker Image
        run: |
          KONSOLIDIERUNG_IMAGE=<docker-tag-prefix>:${{github.event.inputs.konsolidierung_tag}}
          echo "Konsolidierung image: $KONSOLIDIERUNG_IMAGE"
          echo "Produktion image:     $PRODUKTION_IMAGE"
          docker login --username ${{secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USER}} --password ${{secrets.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}} <docker-registry>
          docker pull $KONSOLIDIERUNG_IMAGE
          docker tag $KONSOLIDIERUNG_IMAGE $PRODUKTION_IMAGE 
          docker push $PRODUKTION_IMAGE

      - name: Create Git Tag
        run: |
          echo "github.event.inputs.konsolidierung_tag: ${{github.event.inputs.konsolidierung_tag}}"
          GIT_HASH=$(echo "${{github.event.inputs.konsolidierung_tag}}" | awk -F'-' '{print $3}')
          VERSION_TAG=$(echo "${{github.event.inputs.konsolidierung_tag}}" | awk -F'-' '{print $1}')
          CURRENT_TAG=produktion-current
          echo "Push tag $VERSION_TAG to $GIT_HASH"
          git tag $VERSION_TAG $GIT_HASH
          git tag -f $CURRENT_TAG $GIT_HASH
          git push origin $VERSION_TAG
          git push -f origin $CURRENT_TAG




Please include your workflow. That would be helpful.

Added workflow file, had to remove some proprietory information but semantics should be the same

Thanks! How do you use it and from what branch?

I trigger it as an action from the web ui and enter the docker image that should be used as base. As branch for the execution I use main.

Right. The only plausible reason seems to be that you're doing a shallow clone and the commit you want to tag isn't pulled in this case i.e. fetch-depth: 1 (default). You might want to verify this whether the commit you're trying to tag exists or not. You can use fetch-depth: 0 to fetch all the commit history with actions/checkout. See https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#usage for more details on this. Also, you might want to use its latest version i.e. v4.

Thanks! I will have a look. Thank you for your time.

You're welcome! This scenario can easily be reproduced by running this workflow to tag an older commit (second last or older).
